# Find all complex numbers $z=a+bi$ such that $z^3=8$.

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all complex numbers $z=a+bi$ such that $z^3=8$.
 I'll be happy if someone say me with what steps I have to start solving this problem.

Comment: Hint: write $a=2e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: i dont understand it

Comment: z=a+bi, just a typo and then $z^3=8$, just check your exercise

Comment: The problem is that you are using the letter $a$ to mean two different things, when you write $a=a+bi$.

Comment: Oh. ok my apologise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach:

You have $z^3-8=0$.

Factor this to $(z-2)(z^2+2z+4)=0$ and then solve in the usual ways

Answer (score 2):

Just compute $(a+bi)^3$ and set the real part equal to $8$ and the imaginary part equal to $0$. Then you have two equations and two unknowns.

Comment: It helps that one of the solutions is obvious

Comment: @Henry Agreed, in this case it does.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Write $z=2w$. Then $z^3=8$ iff $w^3=1$. Can you solve this?

Comment: It seems,that $z=2$ but can we get another two answer from this?

Comment: I assumed you knew about roots of unity...

Answer (score 0):

$z^3-8=0$

$(z-2)(z^2+2z+4)=0$

$z=2$ or $z=-1\pm (-3)^{1/2}$
equation may be solved using quadratic equation

Comment: This is already an answer.